# Не работает min-width

Tags: width

Есть кнопки,реализованы через тег "а". Для них в теме шаблона WP прописаны стили которые задают фон,цвет и как я понял ширину.Ширина кнопок меняется только от количества символов которые написаны на ней. Причем у кнопок не задано никакого класса,но они все равно имеют оформление,а не выглядят просто ссылкой.

Дело в том,что кнопки располагаются одна под другой,а из за того что количество символов на них разное,то и ширина получается разная,что смотрится совсем плохо.

В других случаях,на этом же сайте,такой вопрос решался прописыванием (для кнопок которые должны были быть одинакового размера) мин-вид:230px;макс-вид:230px;

Сейчас почему-то мин и макс вид не работают.Пробовал прописывать через импортант - ничего. Подскажите пожалуйста,как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Причем у кнопок не задано никакого класса,но они все равно имеют оформление,а не выглядят просто ссылкой.

Потому что стили можно прописать и без класса, просто на элемент .

> Сейчас почему-то мин и макс вид не работают.

Потому что элемент  - строчный, и получает ширину содержимого. Его надо сделать блочным и спокойно задать ширину:

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```